# Как поменять версию загруженного пакета в NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Я разрабатывал electron приложение и обнаружил что `Electron.BrowserWindowConstructorOptions` ведет себя странно, а именно свойства `maxWidth` и `minWidth` просто не работают. Как оказалось это не я тупой, это новый electron не стабилен и теперь мне, в уже написанном, проекте нужно поменять версию electron с 12.0.1 на 11.2.3. Как это сделать? желательно через консоль.

Comment: в `package.json`

Comment: тогда версия не поменяться, а только у packege.json будет другое содержание

Comment: надо обновить еще пакеты `npm update`

Comment: ну это уже сработает

Comment: как оказалось я таки тупой потому что свойство maxWidth все еще не работают

Answer (score 0):

после еще нескольких минут в гугл я понял что можно просто удалить electron и установить его как `electron@11.2.3`. https://dev-gang.ru/article/npm-ustanovka-opredelennoi-versii-paketa-o9yeyu38qz/